# Listing SQL Database Servers using Get Servers request + Restful service

Tags: rest, azure, azure-sql-database

I tried using "enumerating servers" Get Servers option in REST API.

I tried with multiple options to connect to the server. But  i am either getting an error "Connection refused" or "Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 Tunnel Connection Failed" [with proxy].

I am able to perform other actions like "Get Images, Get Hosted Services ..etc" successfully using the same proxy settings. The connection was smooth that time.

Below are the details:

Request URI  : https://management.database.windows.net:8443//servers.

x-ms-version : 1.0

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is due to firewall restriction at 8443. When i opened it , the above error message has gone. Now struck with "HTTP error 500 : Internal Server Error"..Research still going on with azure!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by your proxy and/or firewall since the Windows Azure SQL Database Management API runs on port 8443. As your network administrators to allow connections to port 8443.

Comment: I am trying to connect from one of my centos box where iptables services status is stopped !

Comment: Could you try this to see if it can connect to port 8443: `telnet -d management.database.windows.net 8443`

Comment: Yes Sandrino , you are rite ..the firewall was at network level. I have opened it up  and now i am getting "HTTP error 500 : Internal Server Error".. Any thoughts on this !!!

Comment: @AnandSrinivasan, I've been getting that error on my hosted API since yesterday as well, i have submitted a ticket since everything was fine a day ago.

Comment: @Sandrino , thanks a lot. Please let me know if you get some update on this.